# React.js : reusable components vs mixin's utility functions

Tags: javascript, architecture, reactjs, mixins

Let's say my react.js app is going to display dates and I would like to apply the format that is set in the client's browser/OS. There are multiple components that show dates and I can use a couple of ways to share the code between them.

1.Re-usable React.js components like:

```
var React = require('react');

module.exports = React.createClass({
    render : function(){
        if(this.props.value === null || this.props.value===undefined)
            return false;
        var formattedValue =  new Date(this.props.value).toLocaleDateString();
        return(
            <span>
                {formattedValue}
            </span>
        );
    }
});
```

and then use them like:

```
var DateFormatter = require('./../formatters/Date');
<DateFormatter value={invoice.date} />
```

2.Utility functions shared via React.js mixins, i.e.:

```
module.exports = {
    renderDate : function(dateValue){
        if(dateValue === null || dateValue===undefined)
            return false;
        var formattedValue =  new Date(dateValue).toLocaleDateString();
        return(
            <span>
                {formattedValue}
            </span>
        );
    }
}
```

and then just add the mixin to a component and use something like

```
{this.renderDate(invoice.date)}
```

To me it seems that there is no much difference between these 2 approaches for now. But I would love to hear the opinion of community about pros and cons of each solution. TIA!

Comment: mixins are basically inheritance.  they are generally for programmers who don't know what they're doing, and typically you're just significantly better of using basic functions with parameters.  Don't bother worry about the concept, it's just a side effect of javascript having stuff like Object.assign and the stupid crap programmers will do when given tools that let them do whatever they want.

Answer (score 5):

One aspect is performance: if you write a component to display the date like you did above, you can mark it with [PureRenderMixin](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html), as the rendered output relies only on the the props. This might speed up the rendering a bit, as the formatting only needs to be done when the date changes.

From clean code point of view, I would either write a component or use a non-react utility function that just formats the date to a string - no need to couple the date formatting and dom elements. Something like:

```
function formatDate(dateValue){
    if(dateValue == null)
        return ""
    return new Date(dateValue).toLocaleDateString()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. in general the code might use quite a lot of html markup in a returned value. PureRenderingMixin looks interesting, I didn't know about it before..